# How do I prevent iPhoto from opening every time I plug in my iPhone

Tags: iphone, photos.app

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent iPhoto to open everytime I plug my iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16641/how-can-i-prevent-iphoto-to-open-everytime-i-plug-my-ipad)

Every time I plug in my iPhone to my MacBook Air iPhoto pops open, how do I make it stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at this question: [How can I prevent iPhoto from opening everytime I plug my iPad/iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16641/how-can-i-prevent-iphoto-to-open-everytime-i-plug-my-ipad)

The summary is that Image Capture has an option to change what happens when a camera is attached to the computer.